# How to use a variable as a method name using dynamic objects

Tags: c#, signalr

In SignalR there is public property defined in the HubConnectionContext as such:

```
public dynamic All { get; set; }
```

This enables users to call it like: `All.someMethodName();`  which is brilliant.

I now would like to call this using an incoming parameter in my function.  How can I do this?

As in:   `All.<my variable as method name>();`

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks

**EDIT** example:

```
    public void AcceptSignal(string methodToCall, string msg)
    {
        Clients.All.someMethod(msg);       // THIS WORKS
        Clients.All.<methodToCall>(msg);   // THIS DOES NOT WORK (But I would like it to!)
    }
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear?

Comment: You would need to use reflection. Something like `All.GetType().GetMethod(theParameter).Invoke(All, new object[] { });`.

Comment: Thanks Jeppe - this would slow down the calls to much...  If that is the only way I may have to do things differently!

Comment: Using `dynamic` already slows things somewhat down. Try a solution with reflection and see if it performs well enough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While I love all the fun reflection answers, there's a much simpler and faster way to invoke client hub methods using a string as the method Name.

`Clients.All`, `Clients.Others`, `Clients.Caller`, `Clients.AllExcept(connectionIds)`, `Clients.Group(groupName)`, `Clients.OthersInGrouop(groupName)`, and `Clients.Client(connectionId)` are all dynamic objects, but they also all implement the [IClientProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj918974%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) interface.

You can cast any of these dynamic objects to an `IClientProxy`, and then call [Invoke(methodName, args...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.iclientproxy.invoke%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public void AcceptSignal(string methodToCall, string msg)
{

    IClientProxy proxy = Clients.All;
    proxy.Invoke(methodToCall, msg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to achieve this:

```
Type allType = All.GetType();
// GetType() may return null in relation to dynamics objects
if (allType != null)
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = allType.GetMethod(methodToCall);
    methodInfo.Invoke(All, null);
}
```

Comment: `GetMethod` may return null if there is something like `ExpandoObject` behind `dynamic`

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'll include that in my answer.

Comment: The GetType() returns a ClientProxy but the next statement 'GetMethod' returns a null (the method doesn't exist)... But we know that because it is a dynamic object ( I am trying to add this method!)

Comment: Just updated my question.  Bearing in mind that the 'All' part is a dynamic public property I have to draw the conclusion this is not going to work...  It's ok - I can approach it differently - I was just curious if there was a way of doing this...

Comment: Try this example: `dynamic all = new ExpandoObject(); all.Hello = (Action<string>)(name => { Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", name); });` Then in some sense `all` has a method `Hello`, because you can say `all.Hello("John");`. But will `Type.GetMethod` find the `Hello` in this case? No, as @IlyaIvanov said.

Comment: @Marcel Will it always be a [ClientProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.clientproxy.aspx)? Because then you can use `((ClientProxy)All).Invoke(methodToCall)`, maybe.

Comment: Yes, totally clear now, and I agree. Thanks for the great comments. What should I do now? Delete the answer? Not sure...

Comment: @JohnWillemse If you deleted, these comments would also disappear. Your solution works in _some_ cases. Only maybe not when the object behind the `dynamic` keyword is in itself dynamic, like with SignalR (it seems).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - it WORKS - this is brilliant! Clearly it works through the casting to ClientProxy but it is exactly what I need.  Thanks to all contributors!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void AcceptSignal(String methodToCall, String msg) {
    var count=(
        from target in new[] { Clients.All }
        from memberInfo in ((Type)target.GetType()).GetMember(methodToCall)
        where MemberTypes.Method==memberInfo.MemberType
        let methodInfo=memberInfo as MethodInfo
        let paraInfos=methodInfo.GetParameters()
        where null!=paraInfos.FirstOrDefault(x => msg.GetType()==x.ParameterType)
        select methodInfo.Invoke(target, new object[] { msg })
        ).Count();
}
```

Comment: Can you test if `((ClientProxy)(Clients.All)).Invoke(methodToCall, msg)` works, for me?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Are you talking about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.clientproxy.invoke.aspx)?

Comment: @Jeppe That WORKS!! Brilliant! - not sure how I can award the answer to you! :)    Thanks very much!

Comment: @Marcel Great. I submitted an answer, so you can accept that if you care.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to find the method. But this will only work if it is a "real" non-dynamic method which is defined in the usual non-dynamic way, only hidden behind the `dynamic` keyword.

If however the object `All` is truely dynamic, like an `ExpandoObject` or something else deriving from `System.Dynamic.DynamicObject`, the "method" could be something that was only associated with the type at runtime, and in that case `typeof(All).GetMethod` won't find anything.

It was Ilya Ivanov who originally pointed this out, in a comment to [John Willemse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16079971/1336654). It became apparent that the object is a [`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ClientProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.clientproxy.aspx) instance.

Therefore, from the documentation of that type, the solution is:

```
string methodToCall = XXX;
string msg = YYY;
((ClientProxy)(Clients.All)).Invoke(methodToCall, msg);
```