# Call to a specific Client (using Invoke) fails in SignalR - conversion issue

Tags: signalr

Can anyone explain me why the second call (to an individual client) is invalid?

```
IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SymHubGrid>();

((ClientProxy)(hubContext.Clients.All)).Invoke(method, msg);   // OK

((ClientProxy)(hubContext.Clients.Client(hubConnID))).Invoke(method, msg);  // FAIL
```

It fails with the following exception:
{Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ConnectionIdProxy' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ClientProxy

It is connected to my earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079813/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-method-name-using-dynamic-objects).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Oeps - found the answer - I need to cast to the IClientProxy - NOT the actual proxy!

Thanks to halter73 in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079813/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-method-name-using-dynamic-objects/16090685#16090685):

It works fine like this:  (Note the IClientProxy!)

```
IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SymHubGrid>();

((IClientProxy)(hubContext.Clients.All)).Invoke(method, infoDown);

((IClientProxy)(hubContext.Clients.Client(hubConnID))).Invoke(method, infoDown);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast it to ClientProxy in order to call Invoke off of it. hubContext.Clients.All.Invoke( method, msg ) is all you need. Actually, you don't need invoke at all, just hubContext.Clients.All.method( msg );

Comment: Thanks but I do need to cast it somehow so I can call Invoke.  I NEED this since I don't know the method to call until runtime - please see me earlier related post.

Comment: Have you tried the bare Invoke without cast? I looked at the SignalR code and Invoke( method, msg ) should work.

Comment: Looking at your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16090685/645 looks to be right.