# How do I call a SiganlR Client method with the method string?

Tags: c#, signalr

Is there away to avoid using the dynamic methods to call client methods from a Hub? I currently have...

```
this.Clients.Client(connectionID).MyClientMethod("Hello");
```

But I want to be able to do it like this...

```
this.Clients.Client(connectionID).Execute("MyClientMethod", "Hello");
```

I've search the various methods exposed on the server side and read the SignalR guides but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16090685/3130094

Comment: Hey thanks for the link. Sometimes no matter what you search for you just can't find an answer, then it's obvious after its pointed out :-)